# Remove Even numbers from stack up to int k

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I'm trying to write a recursive function that removes the first k even numbers from the stack. If there are less than k even elements in the stack, just remove all even elements by not using any loops or data structures other than the stack passed in as a parameter. I have this but I can't figure out how to incorporate k correctly

```
public static int removeEvenNumbers(Stack<Integer> stack, int k) {
    if (k <= 0 || stack.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (stack.peek() % 2 == 0) {
        stack.pop();
        return 1 + removeEvenNumbers(stack, k - 1);
    } else {
        int removed = stack.pop();
        int returns = removeEvenNumbers(stack, k);
        stack.push(removed);
        return returns;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't verifying **K** after removing a element, so if you just removed a element with `K = 1`, then you should stop.

```
public static int removeEvenNumbers(Stack<Integer> stack, int k) {
    if (k <= 0 || stack.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (stack.peek() % 2 == 0) {
        stack.pop();
        return k > 1 ? removeEvenNumbers(stack, k - 1) : 1;
    } else {
        int removed = stack.pop();
        int returns = removeEvenNumbers(stack, k);
        stack.push(removed);
        return returns;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i ask what the ? does

Comment: It's a ternary operator, defined by CONDITION ? TRUE : FALSE
It's the same as:
if(CONDITION){
 TRUE
} ELSE {
FALSE
}

Comment: thanks recursion is so confusing to me

Comment: And bro, if you got your answer, please mark it as accepted. It's always good to vote for the answer too

Comment: Why does it need to return an int?

Comment: @ChengThao It dosn't, but it was already like this in the code, maybe it will be used for another class